# Prove that the equation $Ax+Bu=0$ has a solution $u$ for every $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, stability-theory

We know that

$\text{rank}(\lambda I-E, F)= 2n$ (full row rank) for all $\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C} \mid \Re(\lambda) \ge 0\}$
where E=$\left(\begin{matrix}
        A_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} \\
        -I_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$,F=$\left(\begin{matrix}
        B_{n\times p} \\
        0_{n\times p} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$,
$A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ is a $n \times p$ matrix,and $\lambda$ is a complex number with zero or positive real part.

With this assumption, I want to prove that the following equation

$$Ax + Bu = 0$$

for every possible $x$, we can always find a solution for $u$, where $x$ is a $n\times 1$ real vector and $u$ is a $p\times 1$ real vector.

I also guess that these two conditions are equivalent. However I cannot figure out the proof. At least, I want to prove that the first condition implies the second one.

(This is about the Hautus test/theorem in control theory)

(Edit: this question is only meaningful when n <= p)

Comment: Does $\text{rank}(\lambda I - A,B) = n$ mean $\text{rank}(\lambda I - A)=\text{rank}(B)=n$ ?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. It just means, the matrix (λI−A,B) is row full rank. And the question has been edited. I made something wrong with the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $rank[\lambda I-E, F]=2n$ for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(\lambda)\geq 0$ it also holds for $\lambda=0$. Hence 
$$rank\left[\matrix{-A & 0 & B\\\mathbb{I} & 0 & 0}\right]=2n$$
From standard rank properties we also have
$$rank\left[\matrix{-A & 0 & B\\\mathbb{I} & 0 & 0}\right]=rank\left[\matrix{-A  & B\\\mathbb{I}  & 0}\right]$$ and it is easy to prove that this matrix has full row rank $2n$ iff $rank(B)=n$. This means that the $n\times n$ matrix $BB^T$ is nonsingular and a solution to $Ax+Bu=0$ is given by
$$u^*=-B^T(BB^T)^{-1}Ax$$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out what you actually mean. First, in my case, n > p, thus rank(B) cannot be n. Besides, how can you conclude $BB^T$  is nonsingular ? It think the latter is the key.

Comment: In addition, this should always be true no matter n > p or n < p.

Comment: @ShuhuaGao Well, you need $p\geq n$ or else for $\lambda=0$ the matrix $[\lambda I-E,F]$ cannot have rank equal to $2n$ as $n$ columns are zero and  $rank[-E,F]\leq \min\{2n,n+p\}$.

Comment: Sorry again.  In fact I want to prove that this equation has solutions for n > p. But it turns out if n >p, then the former assumption cannot be true since the matrix can not have a rank of 2n. My problem is meaning less now. I will delete it soon.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much anyway.